# Can spring oauth2 security on spring cloud gateway support POST request?

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

With Spring Cloud Gateway using spring security and oauth2 libraries, trying to make a web request for a given URL with http POST. Seeing that the spring library does not remember the original path, and returns to '/' after completing the OAuth flow. This works fine, while doing a http GET, Spring remembers the request path and redirects to it after the OAuth flow.

Tested with both Spring Boot 2.7.1/Spring Cloud 2021.0.3 and Spring Boot 3.0.10/Spring Cloud 2022.0.3.

Comparing the logs between POST and GET requests, it looks like the Spring library tries to match with '/** GET' path. The POST does not match, while the GET matches and gets its path stored in session before starting the OAuth flow.

**Logs for POST:**
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : All requestMatchers returned true
DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint@86a1310
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using OrServerWebExchangeMatcher{matchers=[PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/**', method=GET}]}
o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/**', method=GET}
athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'POST /resource/userDetails' doesn't match 'GET /**'
o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Did not match
o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy  : Redirecting to '/oauth2/authorization/entiam-uhg'

**Logs for GET:**
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : All requestMatchers returned true
DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint@6dc96ce
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using OrServerWebExchangeMatcher{matchers=[PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/**', method=GET}]}
o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/**', method=GET}
athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/resource/userDetails'; against '/**'
o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : matched
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher{matcher=OrServerWebExchangeMatcher{matchers=[PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/favicon.*', method=null}]}}
o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/favicon.*', method=null}
athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /resource/userDetails' doesn't match 'null /favicon.*'
o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
.w.s.u.m.NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher : matches = true
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
.s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, */*;q=0.8]
.s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : Processing text/html
.s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : text/html .isCompatibleWith text/html = true
.s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : All requestMatchers returned true
o.s.s.w.s.s.WebSessionServerRequestCache : Request added to WebSession: '/resource/userDetails?'

---

Question: Is there a way to add support for Spring to remember request url for POST unauthenticated requests?